# Remove FloatingActionButton border programmatically?

Tags: android, floating-action-button

The `FloatingActionButton` comes pre-configured with a 0.5dp border, which goes against Google's own Material guidelines.

You can remove the border in XML via `app:borderWidth = 0dp`

Is there a way to change this property programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

There's no a clean way of doing it.

You can do it through reflection, with the following code (Kotlin):

```
val button: FloatingActionButton     // your button, initialized someway

// set the field mBorderWidth of your button, it's not enough to do this because this value has already been consumed for drawing the button's background; it shouldn't be necessary, anyway set it...
val fieldBorderWidth = FloatingActionButton::class.java.getDeclaredField("mBorderWidth")
fieldBorderWidth.isAccessible = true
fieldBorderWidth.setInt(button, 0)

// the trick is to call again setBackgroundDrawable (it's already been called inside of the constructor) on the field mImpl of the FloatingActionButton; you can call it with the button's parameters but passing 0 as borderWidth. So obtain the needed button's parameters and call that method
// (since all these fields and methods are private you must set everything as accessible)

// get button's parameters
val fieldBackgroundTint = FloatingActionButton::class.java.getDeclaredField("mBackgroundTint")
fieldBackgroundTint.isAccessible = true
val fieldBackgroundTintValue = fieldBackgroundTint.get(button)
val fieldBackgroundTintMode = FloatingActionButton::class.java.getDeclaredField("mBackgroundTintMode")
fieldBackgroundTintMode.isAccessible = true
val fieldBackgroundTintModeValue = fieldBackgroundTintMode.get(button)
val fieldRippleColor = FloatingActionButton::class.java.getDeclaredField("mRippleColor")
fieldRippleColor.isAccessible = true
val fieldRippleColorValue = fieldRippleColor.get(button)

// get button's mImpl field
val methodGetImpl = FloatingActionButton::class.java.getDeclaredMethod("getImpl")
methodGetImpl.isAccessible = true
val fieldImplValue = methodGetImpl.invoke(button)

// get mImpl's setBackgroundDrawable method and call it
val methodSetBackgroundDrawable = fieldImplValue.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("setBackgroundDrawable", ColorStateList::class.java, PorterDuff.Mode::class.java, Int::class.java, Int::class.java)
methodSetBackgroundDrawable.isAccessible = true
methodSetBackgroundDrawable.invoke(fieldImplValue, fieldBackgroundTintValue, fieldBackgroundTintModeValue, fieldRippleColorValue, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer, I have a question: why does this work only if I set value to 0?

Comment: It doesn't work because if you just set that value to 0 the new value is just ignored because that value has already been used to produce the background drawable and it will never been used again, unless you call setBackgroundDrawable.